# Is it worth to have Redis as cache for DNS records using Unbound

Tags: caching, redis, dns

There is a possibility to have the integration of Unbound DNS server with Redis as cache back-end.

What do you think is this worth? How much latency will it add (on your opinion)?

Thank you!